# React listed objects unmount on state change

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, state

I have two components in my react (ts) app.

App.tsx:

```
import { useState } from 'react'
import Number from './Number'
import './App.css'

function App() {
    const [list, setList] = useState(["1", "2", "3", "4"]);
    const [x, setX] = useState({});

    function ComponentList(){
        return(<>
            {list.map(i => <Number num={i} key={i}/>) }
        </>)
    }

    return (
        <div className="App">
            <ComponentList/>
            <div onClick={()=>{
                setX({});
            }}>Update</div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default App
```

Number.tsx:

```
import React, {useState} from 'react'

type props = {
    num: string
}

function Number({num}:props) {
    const [color, setColor] = useState("rgb(0, 0, 0)");

    return (
        <div style={{color: color}} onClick={()=>{
            setColor("rgb(255, 255, 255)");
        }}>
            {num}
        </div>
    )
}

export default Number
```

Here's the problem:
When any state on the parent component (App.tsx) changes, the Number components in the list re-mount, resetting all their states to initial value. How can I get rid of this problem while keeping the list component?

The issue is very simple to re-create. When you use these two components in a react app and click the numbers to change their color, the color is reset upon clicking the "update" button, which seems illogical to me since the "setX" call doesn't change anything about the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function App() {
    // ...

    function ComponentList(){
        // ...
    }
}
```

You've defined `ComponentList` *inside* of `App`. This isn't supported. Every time `App` rerenders, you create a brand new definition for `ComponentList`. Its code may have the same text as the previous one, but it's a different function, so a different component type as far as react is concerned. So react has to unmount the old ones and mount the new ones.

The fix is to move the component out. You'll need to change `list` to be a prop instead of a closure variable

```
function App() {
  const [list, setList] = useState(["1", "2", "3", "4"]);
  // ...
  <ComponentList list={list}/>
  // ...
}

function ComponentList({ list }){
  return(<>
    {list.map(i => <Number num={i} key={i}/>) }
  </>)
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Never thought about that being different. Works like a charm with that change

Answer (score 1):

You created your `ComponentList` inside the parent, and since you don't use `useCallback`, it is recreated when the parent re-render.
Here is how to implement both solutions, but the best one is to take your component outside of the parent :

```
import React from 'react';
import './style.css';

// Solution 2
function ComponentList({ list }) {
  return (
    <>
      {list.map((i) => (
        <Number num={i} key={i} />
      ))}
    </>
  );
}

export default function App() {
  const [list, setList] = React.useState(['1', '2', '3', '4']);
  const [x, setX] = React.useState({});

  // Solution 1
  // const ComponentList =  React.useCallback(() => {
  //     return(<>
  //         {list.map(i => <Number num={i} key={i}/>) }
  //     </>)
  // }, [])

  return (
    <div className="App">
      {/* <ComponentList /> solution 1 */}
      <ComponentList list={list} /> {/* Solution 2 */}
      <div
        onClick={() => {
          setX({});
        }}
      >
        Update
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

function Number({ num }) {
  const [color, setColor] = React.useState('rgb(0, 0, 0)');

  return (
    <div
      style={{ color: color }}
      onClick={() => {
        setColor('rgb(255, 255, 255)');
      }}
    >
      {num}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Here is [the repro on Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-hakaye?file=src%2FApp.js)
Also, here is a [video of Jeff Herrington](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2sAdzy90GtE) about this exact problem.

Comment: Thanks! Already got the answer from someone else 5 minutes ago but I appreciate the effort! Have a great day dude

Comment: @MaximilianYoshi Yeah I know, I just thought that would be interesting for you to know multiple solution to fix this kind of problem. I also added a video about this exact problem, have a look at it !